# How can I prevent retracting of my listinstance each new deployment from Visual Studio?

Tags: list, visual-studio, retraction

I am using sp2013 and vs2013. I have a solution with some list instances and contenttypes. Every time I do a deployment from Visual Studio the existing listinstance will be retracted and I lost my items. There will come a new listinstance which is clean without items. I forget some option in Visual Studio to prevent this behaviour. How can I setup vs to prevent retracting this listinstance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, you should see a Deployment Conflicts dialog box when you redeploy your solution to your development computer; this should have warned you that your existing list instance would be overwritten. To change this behavior, select the List Instance in Solution Explorer, and then change the Deployment Conflict Resolution property (in the Properties window) to None. If this property is set to Automatic, then existing items will be automatically overwritten without the dialog.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee330922(VS.100).aspx